# Related to Ad network and Banner per Apps

Tags: xcode6, admob

This is not a programming but the best practice question. I have been looking for answer on internet but no success so far.

Question is very simple. 
Do you guys keep only one banner per app or one banner per view. 
I have app which is 4 tabs and having 2 navigation drill down. Its pretty basic app and things are already out of in my admob dashboard. 
So I am here. seeking advice from people who have multiple apps on appstore. 
How you manage ?
If I am keeping only one admob signature per app. would it affect my impression. 
I am thinking to have one banner and one interstitial per app. 
Don't know if that right thing to do. 
Please suggestion.

PS: I know its not programming question, but its not useless question. I am sure there are people like me out there.

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to get overly crowded. One banner and one interstitial is good. Because interstitial ads are so effective, you might even consider taking out the banner if you get complaints about it. If you're doing interstitial ads on a game that finishes quickly, you might consider implementing a boolean so that it runs every *other* time the player dies.

At this point in the development, I'd focus on what the user is going to see and think. If your app is heavy handed on ads, it will drive away your users. It's really not unlike the history of U.S. tariffs on foreign goods. The lower the %, the more money we actually collected:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tariffs_in_United_States_history#Tariff_revenues

Comment: if I have one banner signature. Would that served the purpose in all the views and It wont affect the revenue. Right ?

Comment: Correct. You really only need one signature per type of ad in the app. You get paid per click, not per view.